# Run Java Applet in html, Main class is X.jar/s/main.class

Tags: java, applet

How i can run the applet if the main class is inside a folder inside the jar file.

X.jar contains :
S (folder) main class in it
META-INF (folder) MANIFEST.MF in it

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is an executable jar then you can run it on command line like this:

```
java -jar X.jar
```

For normal jar try this:

```
java -cp pathtoX.Jar YourMainClass
```